# How to get the number of concurrent connections of HTTP in ubuntu server

Tags: server

In ubuntu server, I established a http server, then I want to get the number of concurrent connections accessing http server in one second.

So, are there tools or commands to get the number?

By the way, if I want to get the number of concurrent connections by Python. How to program?

Thanks!

Comment: There are tons of options, apachetop is one.

Comment: try this useful link [log network activity in ubuntu server](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97702/log-network-activity-in-ubuntu-server).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at netflow options for the most detailed connections.

Netflow can be collected locally using [argus](http://qosient.com/argus), and parsed using command line curses tools, or used later in lib bindings.

A opensource GPLv2 netflow tool such as `argus`, provides a 'Real Time Flow Monitor' that is designed to perform comprehensive data network traffic auditing.

An example selection you can perform with argus is listed below:

To see the TopN 25 talkers, based on byte count, on a link between 2pm and 2:15 pm, getting Argus data from the file .

`ramon -TopN -N 25 -t 2-2:15 -r`